# How can I reduce the size of index numbers? (I'm using makeidx package)

Tags: fontsize, indexing, number

I want to reduce the font size of the numbers that shown in index.
\Thanks :)

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`

Comment: @close-voters: Please don't downvote below a score of -1, even if the question in its current form needs some improvement. A score of -1 is enough to show that the question needs work, anything below that is of no use. Also, if you downvote or **vote to close, please leave a comment explaining why you did so, but wait at least 24 hours after asking the OP for improvements to the question before voting to close.** BTW: **Close-voting after 2 minutes is absolutly too fast!**

Comment: @StefanPinnow Please see my comment above!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a special index style:

```latex
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.mst}
delim_0 ", \\indexnumbersize{"
delim_1 ", \\indexnumbersize{"
delim_2 ", \\indexnumbersize{"
delim_n ", \\indexnumbersize{"
delim_t "}"
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[index]{kantlipsum}
\usepackage{imakeidx}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\newcommand{\indexnumbersize}[1]{{\footnotesize#1}} % change to suit

\makeindex

\begin{document}

\kant[1-15]

\printindex

\end{document}
```

I used `imakeidx` for convenience and `hyperref` just to show the code works also with it.

[image]

Comment: Is there a way to reduce the size of the text as well as numbers? For example, if the font size of the document is 11pt, is it possible to set the index font size to 8pt? I asked a question to that effect in this link: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/707646/index-in-table-of-contents-points-to-bibliography