# Index in Table of Contents Points to Bibliography

Tags: table-of-contents, indexing, xepersian

Because of utilizing `xepersian` package, I need to use `makeidx` package in order to produce an index for my book, which I have provided what I consider a minimally working example for it down below. My issues are as follows:

1. When the index ("نمایه" in Persian) is generated in TOC, clicking on it directs me to the bibliography ("کتاب‌نامه" in Persian).
2. I cannot make use of the handy option in `imakeidx` package to use
   smaller font for the index. As can be seen in the MWE, the font size is 11pt; is there a way so that the index font size would be set to for example 8? I do not know how to use the solution
   which [egreg](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/4427/egreg) has proposed [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/503252/how-can-i-reduce-the-size-of-index-numbers-im-using-makeidx-package) with the command `xindy -L persian-variant3 -C utf8 -M numeric-sort -M latex -M latex-loc-fmts -M texindy -M page-ranges %.idx` which is necessary to produce the desired form of index in Persian, as can be seen in the following
   image:

[image]

3. Using the command `\makeindex[columns=3]`, produces an error. Is
   there a way I can produce a three column index?

Here is the content of ch2refs.bib file:

> @article{Balas1976,
> author = {Balas, Egon and Padberg, Manfred W.},
> title = {Set Partitioning: A survey},
> journal = {SIAM Review},
> volume = {18},
> number = {4},
> pages = {710-760},
> ISSN = {0036-1445
> 1095-7200},
> DOI = {10.1137/1018115},
> year = {1976},
> type = {Journal Article}
> }

And here is the MWE:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{book}
\usepackage{amsthm,amssymb}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\usepackage[pagebackref=false,colorlinks,linkcolor=red,citecolor=red]{hyperref}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage[a4paper]{geometry}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{makeidx}
\usepackage{tocbibind}
\makeindex
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage[perpagefootnote=on]{bidi}
\doublespacing
\usepackage{xepersian}
\settextfont[Scale=1]{Tahoma}
\setlatintextfont[Scale=1]{Times New Roman}
\setdigitfont[Scale=1]{Tahoma}
\begin{document}
\twocolumnstableofcontents
\chapter{فصل ۱}
از فرایندهای BALAS و GOMORY در بخش ۲-۲-۴ نام برده شده اما طرح آن‌ها در فصل ۱ انجام گرفته. احتمالاً باید در بخش پیوست‌ها\cite{Balas1976} طرح شود.
هایپرلینک مسائل ۴-۸۶ و ۴-۸۷ در بخش اول توضیحات فصل دوم\index{فصل دوم} اضافه شود.
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{‎‏نمایه}‎
\bibliographystyle{plain-fa}
\bibliography{ch2refs}
\printindex
\end{document}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: To put it simple: `xepersian` and `bidi` change the definition of the `index` environment to *their* liking. Maybe there's a reason.